# regex pattern for number 1 to 11 with space speration

Tags: regex

Need an regex patter to identify an number input with space delimiter, and the number range should be from 1 to 11.

e.g. It should detect following

```
1 2 3
1 11 4 5 6
1 4 3 9
11 4 5
```

e.g It should fail in detecting

```
12 2 3 
1 34 5555
23 3445 566 676544
dds 434 fv 434
dssd s ds sd
```

I came up with

```
^([0]?\d|1[0-1])(([, ]([0]?\d|1[0-1]))*)$
```

But this also detect when I provide

```
1 0 6 7
```

This is not an duplicate question, and I have explained it well enough. Please read question properly and if still someone thinks it's an duplicate question then tell me why it's a duplicate one instead of just marking an duplicate.

Comment: What is your regex so far?

Comment: This regex is for detecting multiple number (range 1 to 11) with space delimiter. I have update the question

Answer (score 0):

`(?:([1-9][01]?)\s+)+` should do it.

Explanation:

`(?:` non capturing group

`([1-9][01]` two digits, first between 1 and 9, second optional

`)\s+)` spaces

`)+` repeat the whole

Comment: @JAL sure. I had replied before it was downvoted

Comment: @prakharsingh95 its not solving the purpose.